# BlockNotify not working

Tags: bitcoind

Hi my configured jsonrpc is following

```
maxconnections=200
maxuploadtarget=20
rpcuser=someusername
rpcpassword=somepassword
daemon=1
keypool=10000
walletnotify=curl "https://someurl.com/walletnotify?transaction_hash=%s"
blocknotify=curl "https://someurl.com/blocknotify?transaction_hash=%s"
```

I am getting notified on both wallet notify and block notify but the problem is the transaction is not the same for both. For Example I get `f793d590bacffce8efd37c1b1e3db254950e925dd5bbd7f3a92c1db142f4dc37`
from wallet notify and

```
00000000000000000038ffec8f035d54558a78e94ae1138ac5bdf1470fb0863f
```

from block notify. Please help what have I missed or done wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-blocknotify` notifies you about a block, not a transaction. The hash you see is a *block* hash
 You'll have to call an RPC like `listtransactions` or `getreceivedbyaddress` on payments you expect.

Alternatively, you can also call `getblock` with the hash you were notified about to see all the transactions in it. I don't recommend that though, as you'll need to deal with the case where your node was down or your system restarted, and you won't get notifications for things that happened during downtime.